# On User Registration with devise gem, run another action in same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an action in my

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def follow_user(following_id)
      Friendship.create(:following_id => following_id, :follower_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

I need to run this action so I can have the user follow a user by default on registration... hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a callback, a method that gets called at a certain point in an object's life, such as `after_create`, on your User model to achieve this.

You can read more about callbacks on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview). Basically, you want to say something like this in your `User` model.

```
after_create: :follow_user
```

Then write your `follow_user` method to achieve what you want. Each time a `User` is created, `follow_user` will be run. Based on your code, I assume `follow_user` is a method that is used anytime one user follows another, not just on creation (hence passing the parameter). To get around passing the parameter in the validation, I would set a default argument so that if the method is called without passing a parameter, the "default" user gets followed. Something like this:

```
def follow_user(following_id = 1)
  code
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. It's common here on Stack Overflow to accept and/or upvote an answer that helped/worked for you. Good luck with the rest of your app!

Comment: hey! sorry dint see this msg till now, Im new here.. :) but I did click accept, i can't up vote till I get 15 reputation..